# Sharply Estimating Pythagorean Triples

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations, sums-of-squares, pythagorean-triples

Given $m,n\in\Bbb N$ with $m<n$, how many pythagorean triples $p^2+r^2=q^2$ satisfy $$m\leq p<r\leq n?$$

Is there a way to give a sharp estimate?

Comment: Is there an asymptotic expression? You are just writing this point counting in a summation formula which does not have use.

Comment: As you know, Arul, you've asked this before: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/214716/bounded-pythagorean-triples  In cases where you feel that a question is wrongly closed, you can make an appeal to reopen here: http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/223/requests-for-reopen-votes But generally, closed questions should not be re-asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [my preprint](http://arxiv.org/abs/1211.6509). Page 12 (this has since been published, but preprint is easiest to access).

Comment: @IgorRovin Is it Theorem $4.4.$?

Comment: I do not this your print suffice for http://mathoverflow.net/questions/219365/primitive-triples-in-a-region

Answer (score 0):

For each type of Pythagorean Triples
$p=2xy$, $r=x^2-y^2$ and $p=x^2-y^2$, $r=2xy$ your inequalities describe a simple region on $Oxy$ plane. Boundary consits from the straight line $2xy=x^2-y^2$ and hyperbolas $2xy=p, x^2-y^2=r$ and $x^2-y^2=p, 2xy=r$.

Comment: Yes. But how big or small is this as a function of $m,n$?

Comment: Find the area of this region.

Comment: is that sufficient? will it be upper or lower bound and what is error term?

Comment: Yes. If the region has perimeter $P$ then the area is $\approx P^2$. The simplest error term for the number of point is $O(P)$ and for the number of primitive points is $O(P\log P)$.

Comment: Arul: as you know, I also gave this answer (cf. my comment above), and gave an explicit integral for the area. I now feel as if I've been wasting my breath.

Comment: @ToddTrimble You also mentioned that you do not know the error bound since it is not your area. It was migrated to stackexchange where no answers were received for several months. I did not know if there was a way to migrate back. That is why I posted a new post and your answer was valuable (only thing was about the error bound). I think Igor Rivin's estimates are good enough for me.

Comment: Arul, since the question is over there, this reposting amounts to cross-posting, which technically is a site violation. At a minimum, what you should have done is link to the post at Mathematics StackExchange (and link from there to here), so that people do not wind up repeating each other's answers, as has happened here. (But, it is also a site violation to repost questions. Just so you know.)

Comment: @Arul Incidentally: if you are unhappy with lack of response to a question, for example the question at M.SE, you can try offering a bounty.

Comment: I do not think I have enough points to offer a bounty