# Primitive triples in a region

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, pythagorean-triples

Are there at least $cn$ Pythagorean triples and at least $dn$ Primitive Pythagorean triples $(A,B,C)$ with $$2^{\frac n2}<A<2^{\frac n2+1}<2^n<B<C<2^{n+1}$$
with some fixed $0<d<c$?

The answer here [Sharply Estimating Pythagorean Triples](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/219323/sharply-estimating-pythagorean-triples) gave $2^n$ of them if $A,B\in(2^n,2^{n+1})$ held (range of $A$ is different here so it is unclear whether there are exponentially ($2^{cn}$ with some $c>0$) many of them or just linearly ($cn$ with some $c>0$) many of them).

I think the answer here is the right asymptotic has to give $\Theta(2^{\frac n4})$ of them but am not sure.

Comment: @AlexeyUstinov No it is not duplicate. The range for $A$ is different and I have also link to same link you provided.